# Logstash: Kafka Output Plugin - Issues with Bootstrap_Server

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to use the logstash-output-kafka in logstash:

**Logstash Configuration File**

```
input {
  stdin {}
}

output {
  kafka {
  topic_id => "mytopic"
  bootstrap_server => "[Kafka Hostname]:9092"
  }
}
```

However, when executing this configuration, I am getting this error:

```
[ERROR][logstash.agent ] Failed to execute action 
{:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, 
:exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Something is wrong 
with your configuration."
```

I tried to change "[Kafka Hostname]:9092" to "localhost:9092", but that also fails to connect to kafka. Only when I remove the bootstrap_server configuration (which then defaults to localhost:9092) then the kafka connection seems to be established.

Is there something wrong with the bootstrap_server configuration of the kafka output plugin? i am using logstash v6.4.1, logstash-output-kafka v7.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo in your configuration. Instead of `bootstrap_server` you need to define `bootstrap_servers`.

```
input {
  stdin {}
}

output {
  kafka {
  topic_id => "mytopic"
  bootstrap_servers => "your_Kafka_host:9092"
  }
}
```

According to [Logstash Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-kafka.html#plugins-outputs-kafka-bootstrap_servers),

> **bootstrap_servers** 
>   Value type is string 
>  
>   Default value is "localhost:9092"  
>  
>  
>   This is for bootstrapping and the producer will only
>   use it for getting metadata (topics, partitions and replicas). The
>   socket connections for sending the actual data will be established
>   based on the broker information returned in the metadata. The format
>   is host1:port1,host2:port2, and the list can be a subset of brokers or
>   a VIP pointing to a subset of brokers.